# Error: postcss-svgo: Error in parsing SVG: Unquoted attribute value with AngularJS and Laravel

Tags: angularjs, webpack, laravel-6

```
> @ production /mnt/d/PHP/project/myApp
> cross-env NODE_ENV=production node_modules/webpack/bin/webpack.js --no-progress --hide-modules --config=node_modules/laravel-mix/setup/webpack.config.js

Error: postcss-svgo: Error in parsing SVG: Unquoted attribute value
Line: 0
Column: 12
Char: \
```

npm run watch, npm run development working fine but npm run production not working. Please help

I am using angularJS and Laravel 6.